Doesn't clean ListView Android Studio
Doesn't clean ListView I tried through notifyDataSetChanged() and through removeAllViews() and removeViews but nothing works
I run another setContentView and get some data. I enter them into the database. I run the old setContentView and it should update there..., but it leaves the old elements there and adds the old ones + 1 new ones. I need the old ones to be deleted and the old ones + 1 new to be added
Here's the code:
public void setadapter(List<Deal> e){
        DealsList=findViewById(R.id.listofbook);
        if(deals.size()>0) {
            deals.clear();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<e.size();i++){
            deals.add(e.get(i));
        }

        stateAdapter=new StateAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, deals);
        DealsList.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Deal selectedDeal = (Deal)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ViewSelectedCard(selectedDeal);
                stateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        DealsList.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
    }

package com.example.projecz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.List;

public class StateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Deal> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int layout;
    private List<Deal> deals;

    public StateAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Deal> deals) {
        super(context, resource, deals);
        this.deals = deals;
        this.layout = resource;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);

        ImageView photoView = view.findViewById(R.id.photobook);
        ImageView fone = view.findViewById(R.id.fone);
        TextView nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.namebookscr);
        TextView priceView = view.findViewById(R.id.price);

        Deal deal = deals.get(position);
        String s=null;
        s=deal.ImageFst;
        Picasso.get().load(s).into(photoView);
        nameView.setText(deal.Name);
        String endprice="";
        if(deal.Price==null){
            endprice="Обмен";
        }
        else{
            if(deal.Exchange==false){
                endprice=deal.Price.toString()+" руб.";
            }
            else{
                endprice="Обмен / "+deal.Price.toString()+" руб.";
            }
        }
        priceView.setText(endprice);
        //fone.setImageResource(R.drawable.fonelist);
        return view;
    }
}

Deal Class:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fzmCYdDSzDOycsHHRZRBhd5Rbo79veqG/view?usp=sharing
Before adding elements:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HxMnr3o95ea_kM5aO6R2Y23XP-hK8pRS/view?usp=sharing
After adding elements:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lctfq5QNx3TRTkge6JlgCM7zRw4lO6ju/view?usp=sharing
I tried through notifyDataSetChanged() and through removeAllViews() and removeViews but nothing works

"nothing works" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

In logCat:
force finish cuj, time out: J<IME_INSETS_ANIMATION::1@0@com.example.projecz>
2024-04-22 15:54:54.490 10571-10571 FrameTracker            com.example.projecz                  E  force finish cuj, time out: J<IME_INSETS_ANIMATION::0@0@com.example.projecz>
2024-04-22 15:54:55.501 10571-10571 FrameTracker            com.example.projecz                  E  force finish cuj, time out: J<IME_INSETS_ANIMATION::1@0@com.example.projecz>

does not work, meaning the list is not cleared of old elements

You tagged with firebase-realtime-database, but at first glance I don't see any calls to the API of that product. I recommend reading how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example, as following the guidance in there makes it much more likely tht someone can help.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

@AlexMamo I added the Deal class code, an example before and after adding elements and removed the tag. But let's get back to the problem, why isn't the list view clearing?

@FrankvanPuffelen I added the Deal class code, an example before and after adding elements and removed the tag. But let's get back to the problem, why isn't the list view clearing?

Please don't share external resources, add the code to your question.
